# Why can't a nullable int be implicitly conversion to an int ? Technical reason or design choice?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

In C#, there is no implicit conversion from the `int?` type to the `int` type.

I have defined the following implicit operator

```
namespace System
{
    public partial struct Int32
    {
        public static implicit operator Int32(int? v)
        {
            return (Int32)(v ?? 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows me to compile the following code

```
int? nullableInt = 0;
Int32 regularInt = nullableInt;
```

but if I define `regularInt` as an `int` instead of `Int32` I get the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I expected `int` and `Int32` to be interchangeable but the C# language clearly hasn't been built with this functionality in mind.

Is there a technical reason behind the impossibility of defining this operation, is it a decision made to prevent potential code smell ?

I'm aware that defining such an implicit operator could result in some very unexpected behavior, as the conversion from a `null` value to a `0` integer doesn't make sense in every situation. This question is more about "why can't it be done" than "why doing it is a *really*  bad idea"

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. `null` isn't 0. `null` means the actual value is unknown. This means that implicit operator is a bad idea. Why the arbitrary conversion to 0? Why not `int.MinValue` or `-1` ?

Comment: Also, as a general rule, implicit conversions are *widening*, that is you can implicitly convert if the type that you're converting to can express all the same values as the type that you're converting from.

Comment: @RenéVogt "int and Int32 are the same" not in the code shown here they're not.

Comment: The compiler got ahead of you, preferring to emit a diagnostic for this very common mistake before considering the conversion operator.  Could be considered a bit of a bug, perhaps, but pretty likely that Eric Lippert disagrees :)  Otherwise a good demonstration that int is not just an "alias" for Int32.

Comment: @HansPassant Because they created a new type with the same name as the system type they're trying to add implicit conversion to, rather than simply putting the implicit conversion in a type that didn't share a name as either type, they simply get behavior they didn't expect, rather than the compiler error you're referring to.

Comment: My compiler issues CS0436, "the type `Int32` in `ThisTerribleIdea.cs` conflicts with the imported type `int` in `mscorlib, ...`" clearly demonstrating your problem. (And why making warnings errors is generally a good idea in C#.) To be sure, the system `Int32` isn't `partial` to begin with, so this could never work. The system types are not "open" in C# and you're not free to tack stuff on. (A language like F# is more relaxed about this.)

Comment: Adding @JeroenMostert's comment, `partial` is a compile-time thing, and only works for two types in the same assembly. The compiler uses both partial definitions when compiling the type. They're not a way to add things to arbitrary types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert partial types are only combined with other partial versions of that type from the same assembly, so even if the system's Int32 was partial, it wouldn't change what this code does.

Comment: @HansPassant According to [the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#simple-types), `int` is an alias for `Int32`. Do you have a reference for your claim?

Comment: @Servy I'd bet most people haven't noticed what the question's code did and took the OP's assertion that this is an implicit conversion operator

Comment: @KennethK. Hans is right. `int` isn't *just* an alias. It's a C# keyword that the compiler maps to `System.Int32`. There are various edge cases where the difference causes problems though [and this is one of them](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-net-primitive-types)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't understand your link. Even it says that `int` is an alias for `Int32` ("In C#, int is just an alias for System.Int32, supported by the C# compiler."). What it also says is that `int` is _not_ an alias for the CLR `int32`, which I don't think is what's being said in this thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code you have doesn't add an implicit conversion from the .NET's nullable int to .NET's int.  It creates a whole new type, called `Int32`, in the `System` namespace, but as it's in a different assembly than Core.dll, it's a different type.  (Take a look at `typeof(int).FullName` and `typeof(int32).FullName` to see this.)

The code you showed to try to test this implicit conversion is set up so that it's trying to convert the system's nullable type to your own new type, and since you created such an implicit conversion, it succeeds.  It fails when you use the system type instead of your own new type because there is no implicit conversion between those types.

You cannot create implicit (or explicit) conversions for types from outside the definition of one of those types, and since you can't access the source of either `Nullable` or the .NET Int32, you can't add an implicit conversion.

Comment: I didn't know I had to be in the defining assembly, I assumed simply writing my code in the right namespace would do the trick. Thank you for proving this stupid idea impossible (don't worry people I'm not actually going to implement that, I just like to explore stuff. It's a good way to learn.)

Comment: @mat I get your point, even though it would be a pretty adventurous to use in daily practice, since implicitly defaulting `null` to `0` could lead to some hard find issues.

Answer (score -1):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions), implicit type conversions are only possible, as long as the conversion is save.

Example from before

```
// Implicit conversion. A long can
// hold any value an int can hold, and more!
int num = 2147483647; 
long bigNum = num;
```

In your case, `int` or `Int32` may be savely converted to `int?` but not vice-versa.

The same applies to type-hierarchy

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

class C : A {}

A var1 = new A(); // Compiles
A var2 = new B(); // Compiles (implicit cast)
B var3 = new B(); // Compiles

// need for explicit cast because instance2 can could also be A or C
B var4 = (B) instance2;

// Throws InvalidCastException
C var5 = (C) instance2;
```

Comment: @mat I just realized, that I kinda missed the point of your question. However im gonna leave it here, since it adds some basic knowledge to servy's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Because the default value of int is 0 but int? by default has a null value which is not a valid int value and will result to an exception.

For instance, 
int x; // declaration result to 0
int? x; // declaration results to null (not valid int value)

Comment: Thanks for your time but this does not answer your question and your claim that `int x` has a value of `0` is not true. `int x` creates an uninitialized variable. Try performing any arithmetic operation with that `x` var and you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @MathieuVIALES If `x` is a class or struct member, you don't need explicit initialization. If that's Josh's intent, he should say so, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Hi @EdPlunkett nice to see you :) Good Point, even though he could have indicated it by adding the `private` keyword and used the default c# naming convention.

Comment: A better example might be `int defaultInt = default(int); int? defaultNullableInt = default(int?);`